# How can I organize this location data (json output) in a text file using PowerShell?

Tags: json, powershell, parsing, text

```
C:\temp\GeoDATA.txt:39:Content           : {"ip":"68.55.28.227","city":"Plymouth","region_code":"MI","zip":"48170"}
C:\temp\GeoDATA.txt:56:Content           : {"ip":"72.95.198.227","city":"Homestead","region_code":"PA","zip":"15120"}
C:\temp\GeoDATA.txt:73:Content           : {"ip":"68.180.94.219","city":"Normal","region_code":"IL","zip":"61761"}
C:\temp\GeoDATA.txt:90:Content           : {"ip":"75.132.165.245","city":"Belleville","region_code":"IL","zip":"62226"}
C:\temp\GeoDATA.txt:107:Content           : {"ip":"97.92.20.220","city":"Farmington","region_code":"MN","zip":"55024"}
```

Each line starts with the path and ends with the closing }

I would like to organize this as a table with the headers being "ip, city, region_code, zip" and the appropriate data below each header. Something like this...

```
ip              city         region_code    zip 
68.55.28.227    Plymouth     MI             48170
72.95.198.227   Homestead    PA             15120
68.180.94.219   Normal       IL             61761
75.132.165.245  Belleville   IL             62226
97.92.20.220    Farmington   MN             55024
```

This is the first 5 lines of a text file with hundreds more, so please keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that file `input.txt` contains data like your sample input data, the following should work:

```
(Get-Content input.txt) -replace '.*: (?=\{)' | ConvertFrom-Json
```

`-replace '.*: (?=\{)'` strips the prefix from each input line using a regular expression, returning only the JSON part:

- `.*:`  matches any sequence of characters followed by `:` and a space.
- `(?=\{)` is a lookahead assertion (`(?=...)`) that matches a single `{` (escaped as `\{`, because `{` has special meaning in regexes
- Since lookaround assertions aren't considered part of the substring matched by the regex, each line is only matched up to the space *before* the `{` that starts the JSON part, and by replacing the matching part with the empty string (implicitly, because no replacement string is given), it is effectively *removed* from each line, leaving just the JSON part.

Piping the result to `ConvertFrom-Json` yields a collection of custom objects whose properties reflect the JSON input, yielding the desired tabular output by default.

Comment: I do have a followup question: 

Many of the IPs in the larger list I have are either no longer valid, or outside the US, and they return a "null" value one, or more, fields. Is there any way to exclude lines that do not have all three fields (City, Region_Code, Zip) populated?

Comment: @JohnnyCarino: Assuming that null values are represented as empty strings or `null` in the JSON, you can pipe to `Where-Object { $_.city.length -gt 0 -and $_.region_code.length -gt 0 -and $_.zip.length -gt 0 }`. If you need further assistance, please create a _new_ question (and feel free to ping me here, if you want my help).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is in the test.txt file.

Try this:

```
$Data = $null
$Table  = @()

$Data = Get-Content C:\Users\lt\AppData\Local\Temp\test.txt


$Data | %{
    $IP = (($_ -split "{")[1] -split "," -split ":")[1] -replace "`"",""
    $City = (($_ -split "{")[1] -split "," -split ":")[3] -replace "`"",""
    $Region_Code = (($_ -split "{")[1] -split "," -split ":")[5] -replace "`"",""
    $ZIP = (($_ -split "{")[1] -split "," -split ":")[7] -replace "}","" -replace "`"",""

    $Table += "$IP,$City,$Region_Code,$ZIP"
}

ConvertFrom-Csv -Header "IP","City","Region_Code","ZIP" -InputObject $Table
```

Please let me know if this helps and don't forget to mark it as answer :).

Comment: Given that the input lines contain valid JSON strings, it seems convoluted to transform the input into CSV first instead. On a general note, it's best to avoid iteratively "extending" an array, because in reality a new array has to be allocated behind the scenes every time `+=` is used, given that arrays are _fixed-size_ data structures.

Comment: @mklement0 Interesting... how would you improve the solution?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Still gave me the desired output, and taught me a few things about syntax. I appreciate it.